# Need tips to get perl running on Ubuntu LAMP with fastcgi/suexec

Tags: perl, apache, ubuntu, fastcgi, suexec

I have perl installed on the server and working fine, but I can't get Apache to serve anything with fastcgi/suexec installed. Below is an example of one of my Apache vhost configs without perl as I can't get anything in there to work with perl:

```
<VirtualHost example.example.example.example:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html

    SuexecUserGroup username username

    ScriptAlias /php-fastcgi/ /home/user/php-fastcgi/
    FCGIWrapper /home/user/php-fastcgi/wrapper .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    Options ExecCGI Indexes

    <Directory /home/user/public_html>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/user_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/user_access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you need to use:

```
use FCGI;
```

in your Perl script and code with FastCGI in mind.  More info can be found here: http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch3perl.htm

The SuexecUserGroup entry looks right and /should/ be all you need to do.  At least, it works on my VPS running RedHat.